# Why won't background image display?

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to display a background image for a website header, however, it won't display. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matt Hayward's Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">

        </div> <!-- header -->
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div> <!-- navbar -->
        <div id="maincontent">

        </div> <!-- maincontent -->
        <div id="rightmenu">

        </div> <!-- rightmenu -->
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="footer">

    </div> <!-- footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS for the `header` div:

```
#header
{
    background: #fff url(header.png) no-repeat;
    width: 960px;
    height: 121px;
}
```

This is something I have used a hundred times before, and never had problems displaying the background image, so I'm totally perplexed to as to why it isn't working. If anyone can help, that would be great.

I have tried the `url()` property both with and without single quotes, but neither way works.

(I know similar questions have been asked before, and I've looked at several of them but the answers don't solve my problem.)

Comment: Make sure header.png actually exists in the styles folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good. Make sure header.png exists and resides in the styles folder.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. So used to having my stylesheet in the root folder! Thanks!